# How do I use a property from my pom in another xml file?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

How can I pull the value of version from pom.xml and use it in version in appengine-web.xml?

appengine-web.xml

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    ...
    <version>${pom.version}</version>
    ...
```

pom.xml

```
<project>
    ...
    <version>64-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
```

This doesn't work.
When I add appengine-web.xml as a resource, then it does get updated, but copied to WEB-INF/classes in the target folder, and the file that ends up directly in WEB-INF has the original value: `${pom.version}`

Comment: the opposite would work too: using a value from appengine-web.xml to populate pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Maven filters should be able to help you do this.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @antony.trupe Well then configure the plugin correctly. Your question is too general to give you any more specific advice.